# Would a futuristic civilization still use animals for ground transportation?

Tags: science-fiction, fauna, farming

I'm building a fantasy/scifi world, that is set in the distant future,probably in the 10,000's with extremely advanced, basically reality warping  technology that allows for things like FTL travel and force field creation.

I still want to include animals used for personal and trade transportation,global transportation as in going from one area to the other.

How can this be culturally justified?
As in what social framework would get all society members in a post-scarcity society to engage in such medieval transportation? This includes - the full experience of animal transportation. As in, saddling work, feeding the animal, spending hours on the road and rough terrain. Getting your muscles sore, getting dirty and hungry.

Comment: Do you mean 'in general' or do you mean for a commercial application? There are a whole host of reasons one would still use an animal for transport that aren't commercial - but if you want it to be a part of industry, we have to narrow the answer down a bit.

Comment: you may want to read some stuff by Paolo Bacigalupi, he justifies animal power driven society fairly well.

Comment: A Twilight Zone episode from the 1980s depicted exactly this.  The title of the episode is "Quarantine" and it is easily found on YouTube.  Essentially, their world is very advanced, but it is all powered by genetically-engineered organisms who willfully participate and act as the technology.

Comment: VTC:Needs Details or Clarity. What, ***specifically,*** do you mean by "transportation?" Riding a horse in a parade is "transportation." Twenty horses hauling a large cart of hay on England's M5 might be legal, but it might also get you arrested for endangering animals. Militaries might use horses for specific applications, but the U.S. Military discontinued mounted cavalry as a formal division of the army in 1942. If all you're looking for are hobbies and special applications, then VTC:Opinion-Based as trivial brainstorming. I'll gladly retract after your explanation.

Comment: There were horse-drawn tourist vehicles in NYC fairly recently, though pedalled versions seem to have largely replaced them. N To C police used to use horses for some patrols because they were able to go places bicycles/motorcycles couldn't, plus giving the officer a good view over the heads of a crowd, plus simply feeling authoritative, plus again being something the public  enjoyed seeing. The question you need to answer is what specific application calls for this solution: entertainment, versatility, ritual, ostentation, whatever.

Comment: If the Imperium in Warhammer 40k can get away with the widespread use of swords against hyper advanced aliens with no reasonable explanation, so too can you have Chocobos.

Comment: Are you reaching for Ann McCaffrey's Dragon's ability to go "between"? (see [Pern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonriders_of_Pern))

Comment: There's a little movie franchise that has this called "Star Wars".

Comment: Your title and body are asking two different questions.

Comment: @JimmyJames Yes they do... but they do nothing to actually justify it.

Comment: Can you first explain what '… basically reality warping technology' might mean?

Comment: Have you seen no war movies showing mules going where Jeeps cannot?

To go what you prolly see as sideways, how exactly do the riches of Gates, Musk or Zuckerberg affect the poverty of the world's poorest people?

Further, how could the richest living in Paradise ever lift the poorest out of living underneath the arches?

Comment: @Nosajimiki Of course they did. They couldn't adapt the speeders to the cold. That's why Han went out on a tauntaun.

Comment: @JimmyJames except... you then immediately see a bunch of A-wings, AT-ATs, etc. moving about the planet with no problem.  So, that explanation holds water like a sodium bucket.  Also, it does not explain their other uses for animals like the Gungan Cavalry and shield carriers.

Answer (score 23):

(Relatively) **low cost to operate.**

In rural areas of the United States such as Texas, you still see many farmers (esp. ranchers) riding around on horses. This is because horses are (more-or-less) reliable, provide a relatively good solution to the problem (you don't necessarily need the extra speed and carrying capacity of a truck if you're just following a herd of cattle), and require more-or-less the same fuel and upkeep as cows (i.e., plants, lots of space, and the occasional veterinarian visit).

Ranchers still have and use modern technology like pickup trucks; however, a lot of the time a horse is all you need.

EDIT: As @JBH pointed out, horses and other livestock used for transport  have their own unique costs related to them, which more modern vehicles don't.

**Rough terrain.**

Horses, mules, and the like are much better at getting around in rough terrain than most vehicles.

**Tradition.**

Your space farmers have traditionally used draft animals. While they may or may not actually use them much anymore, many still ride space-horses as a hobby.

Comment: A lot of armies (where you'd expect high-tech solutions) still have significant horse or mule corps specifically for rough terrain

Comment: Quite a few police forces still use horses. Even in cities, e.g. the New York City Police Department Mounted Unit. The "Gebirgsjäger" (special mountain troops) of the German Bundeswehr also still has a Mule and Horse unit (https://www.bundeswehr.de/de/organisation/heer/organisation/division-schnelle-kraefte/gebirgsjaegerbrigade-23/einsatz-und-ausbildungszentrum-fuer-tragtierwesen-230) - A mule carries up to 140 kg of weapons and supplies.

Comment: There's a suburb here (Tulsa, OK) where people have been known to take their horse through the drive-through at Sonic. Can see them riding on the roads in North Tulsa on occasion too. However, I think these are more enthusiasts than people using the horses for mundane transportation.

Comment: I live in an area filled with farmers and ranchers. None of them describe their horses as "low cost to operate." Many use ATVs and only use horses as hobbies and because it's cool. I don't know any that use horses as part of their daily work. Horses require daily feeding, regular maintenance to their corrals, medical treatment...  A truck can sit in a garage for months without a second thought. Horses are expensive.

Comment: @JBH Good point. I hadn't thought about those other costs. Relative to the "daily work" part, I used to know some ranchers up in Walla Walla who used horses some, although that was mostly because some of the terrain in their ranch was mountainous.

Comment: At my university, the local police force would get out the horses to manage the crowds on the main bar street on Friday nights. It makes sense that, as a rowdy drunk person, you might assume a cop isn't allowed to hit you or run you over, but horses don't have to follow those rules. More often than not, drunk people respected (and feared) the thousand-pound animal more than the human.

Answer (score 9):

Historical reconstruction, vintage appeal, environmental considerations, economy.. there are plenty of reasons for using animals as power source for transportation.

Sometimes having a donkey to carry up and down stuff between two places is still way more economical than building a road and the necessary infrastructure to support at least 1 car. It can be the same also in k-thousand years.

And no reconstruction of the battle of the Little Big Horn is real if Custer falls from an electric moped...

Comment: And it enhances the outdoors experience. Going rural and medieval has whole communities today who engage in a sanitized medieval experience. And if you have terrain that simply can not be navigated by advance flying vehicles, at least for some stretches it may be the only option. Saddle up!

Answer (score 6):

Under the conditions which applied on Earth, in industrialized countries, railways overtook animal transport in the 19th century and trucks and cars overtook it in the 20th century. A tractor is simply *better* than a yoke of oxen at plowing, a motorbike is *better* than a horse at getting around in reasonably flat land.

But this word I used, *better*, is a value judgement. For most of the time period I mentioned, *better* was measured in factors like dollars per ton per mile, or miles per hour. More recently, *better* gets measured in factors like noise or other emissions. Policies are put in place to encourage the use of mass transit systems and [muscle-powered transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle).

So imagine a civilization where energy use and industrial pollution are heavily taxed.

Comment: While I know what you mean with "heavily taxed" it's equally reasonable to have that society progress away from capitalism, so a monetary incentive manipulating market forces could be unnecessary. Though the (moral/societal) value of silence/emissions etc. still needs to be high

Answer (score 6):

### Extreme inequality

So, your world has *"extremely advanced, basically reality warping technology, with FTL travel, advanced vehicles and stuff"*. But such technology is expensive, and there are many people living in poverty who cannot afford it. Many of them even work in the factories producing the technology which they cannot afford.

Comment: ... like in today's sweatshops...

Answer (score 5):

### Impossible to justify for general use

It will be near impossible to justify. Yes, there is such a thing as impossible to justify. When you take on a set of implicit premises, from environmental, to socio-economical, such as by assuming it is a future version of earth, you get a set of constraints of what is possible, including what is economical and therefore what a naturally evolved society would adopt.

Animals are not economical relative to machine transport in terms of throughput per operating cost, and speed. It is not just a little bit uneconomical. It is drastically more costly to maintain animals for transportation in addition to space.

For example, this [US based site suggests](https://www.farmhousetack.com/blogs/barn-blog/how-much-does-it-cost-to-own-a-horse#:%7E:text=You%20can%20then%20expect%20to,the%20expense%20is%20worth%20it.) in 2022 it costs us\$6-8k annually to *maintain* a horse, in addition to (amortizing) acquisition cost (which totals up to us\$60k, excluding financing). That would still be separate from land cost and other real estate cost. [This site suggests](https://driving.ca/features/shopping-advice/3-year-ownership-costs-ev-gas-pickup-trucks) in 2023, for Canadian readers, it costs ca\$4k to *maintain* a pickup truck. (Acquisition cost ca\$80k, for a new model, excluding financing.) The cost in all categories of energy, acquisition and financing should be a bit less in US. Currency conversion would be around 1.3 ca\$ = 1 us$ around the time of those articles. So you get ~3x the cost but probably more to own a horse. Yet a pickup truck accomplishes more.

If you only need the functionality of horse transport (in terms of speed and capacity), your vehicle cost would be a lot less -- even if you add more terrain requirements for typical well inhabited areas.

You can do your own research to refine the numbers. But the bulk part is so off that refinement is unlikely to reverse the trend exhibited thusfar.

### Specialized examples of use

##### Mountain Terrain

At our present level of technology, one of the only few uses of pack animals that are not hobby/culture based is mountain travel.

The photo below shows the best.

[image]

If you want to use such a patrol route, with our present level of technology, there is no better alternative than the yaks used by the Chinese soldiers in the photo. [Source](http://www.81.cn/bg_208596/jdt_208597/9888591.html)

[Here](https://www.natomultimedia.tv/app/asset/599372) is a short film for pack animals with a German Mountain Infantry unit. [Here](https://www.mcmwtc.marines.mil/Resources/Photos/igphoto/2002980921/) is a photo with a mule taken as highlight to introduce a training course at a US training center for mountain operations. Depending on the climate, yaks, mules, and certain species of horses are the most efficient options for logistics and personnel transport across mountain routes.

Despite of all of the above, if you do not design your terrain and environment in general and design the socio-economical organization as a consequence, one cannot contrive animal use. If it is so uneconomical to transport in general, why would human concentrate around such terrains? Well, they don't. If they did, their society wouldn't advance.

(Of course, you can do whatever you will with your creation. But your question seems centered around what avoids logical fallacy.)

The other problem is the premise of technological advancement. Would flight still be off-limit to daily transportation? If not, why not flight? If bulk capacity is required, why not robotic carriers with legs?

##### Specific Cold Climate

[Mongolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_of_Mongolia) is known for its unpredictable winters, with blizzards, droughts, extreme cold spells etc that make settlements difficult to make economically viable. As such, [nomadic lifestyle](https://tourmongolia.com/meet-mongolians-nomadic-lifestyle/) persists even today. Mongolian nomads do use vehicles. Horses are also in use. I do not know the relative proportion of truck use vs horse use in transportation though.

I would just emphasize the effect of economics here: the nomads are incentivize to use horses and against using trucks. Animals are expensive. But the nomads already have access to them and they are able to breed them within their economical cycles. Maintenance cost is a marginal (cost) addition to their economical cycle. They already have the lifestyle setup -- the know-how, the land, the time spend, etc -- to raise animals. Raising and keeping additional horses for either hobby or transport do not require materially more equipment, land, time etc for them specifically.

Meanwhile, producing vehicles is outside the economical cycle of nomadic lifestyle and thus it can be relatively expensive to them to acquire and maintain vehicles.

For a non-contrived proliferation of animal for transport, you'd need to reverse engineer the environmental, and socio-economical reasons behind it. For the information provided thus far in OP though, everything sounds current earth with typically expected/imagined future tech. With that premise, I do not see animal transport.

Answer (score 3):

**Self Replicating**

Machines need to be built and need factories to build them. Animals just need a breeding pair and some Tom Jones music and you get more of them.

In a colony, you don't have factories so vehicles needs to be shipped in off world. If you ship in a herd of horses, they will breed.

Throw in that they heal by themselves and can also be eaten, it makes sense in a small colony.

With genetic editing, the animals can be high tech as well. They can be stronger, eat just about anything and breed quickly while remaining docile and easy to train.

[image]

Animals would easily the the life blood of a frontier colony

Comment: Animals need air, water, food, moderate temperature &c.- all of that all the time, not only when being used for work. And you can't have them shelved indefinitely.

Comment: @Trang Oul You mean they need air, water, food, moderate temperature just like people do? Well I'd of hoped the planet they were living on had all that else it's going to be bad for the humans too.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on widespread you want the use of animals for transportation to be, there's always the possibility of using them as a sign of social status. (Especially in a heavily industrialized world with little need  or space reserved for fields.) It would be similar to how rich folks nowadays like to keep horses, except more extreme. Just think of what a power move it would be to own a troupe of elephants when most people are confined to living in a tiny little apartment in a skyscraper or space station.

If you're looking for an option to have a vast majority of people and industries using animals for transport, I'd tend to think you need an economic justification for it. Plus, if there's a large population in a highly technological society, how are the animals being kept and maintained? A large animal like a horse or ox needs a lot of food and exercise to be healthy, so you'd have to have a fair amount of infrastructure supporting that. Of course, that might be the economic justification... If MyPersonalDraftHorse Incorporated is a major player in the economy and government, and has been for centuries, they might just have enough influence through lobbying and advertising to keep the industry alive.

Comment: Alr, thanks, I might just go with the former, having animals reserved for the rich and dudes who wanna brag about still having their own giant fields instead of being confined to tight cities.

Comment: I was also going to say status, but I saw your answer. I believe you could even justify most people doing this, not just the rich. Similar now to how most people can afford a pet like a dog, but it's generally the more rich people that will have specific breeds that can cost thousands of dollars. you can adjust these parameters to have ultra rich having the very best breed of the transport animal, then the cheapest breed being at a price that cuts off a certain class of people, wether you want that to be poor or upper middle or lower rich, up to the specifics.

Answer (score 2):

### Gene engineering and nanotech makes them cheap.

Animals are an expensive luxury for people today because food is expensive and raising an animal is hard.

Advanced futuristic tech may make it cheap. You head down to the corner store, buy a horse bag for ten dollars, toss some dirt in and the horse will self assemble ready to go in a few hours. There are no ethical concerns because the horse can be made sentient or non sentient at will.

This is much cheaper than needing to mine out iron and other rare elements for vehicles which go at immense speeds and so need metals for their heat resistance and durability, and is much less dependent on centralized economies. The advanced materials tend to require rare elements and rare materials that require substantial mining operations.

It also allows much more custom mods. Tweak the dial on the horse bag and you can have a unicorn, or change their hair colour, or change their size.

Answer (score 1):

One possible scenario I can think of (I don't know if it has been proposed and if a better solution has taken its place) is dual purpose:

Beasts of burden are grown for their meat. Health awareness encourages people to consume low-fat meat. So, beasts are initially grown as beasts of burden so that they will stay lean and fit. Meat is basically muscle, except for inner organs like the liver and the brain. Once the beast reaches its desired qualities, its meat is good for consumption and it is slaughtered.

Answer (score 1):

## Harder to disable in combat

Animals don't contain electronics which can be remotely controlled, or disabled using an EMP. They can also live of the land, and don't require vulnerable supply lines carrying rare and expensive fuels to drive the modern vehicles.

Answer (score 1):

### For the sheer fun of it!

Humans have kept domesticated animals since prehistory and there's literally no sign of that changing any time soon. If people in your far future world still take dogs for a walk and keep cats as house pets? There will be millions who ride horses for pleasure, go trekking though wilderness with them or take coach rides through towns and cities because they can.

Comment: This is what I was thinking. It may make sense for emotional reasons, like companionship.

Answer (score 0):

Religous believes in reincarnation, make the keeping around of animals absolutly mandatory, otherwise, were would the dead and kharmatic challenged respawn into?
And to give your drunk uncle a chance to respawn as a cloned baby- the paryerMill AI has assigned his dharma to a transport donkey, carrying those full cegs from the brewery in the valley up to the monastry.

Sometimes, when the wind is right, and the carawann with the whip asks aloud "Whos thirsty!" you can still here the "iAam"..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps their fondness of animal transport came about because of and not despite the technological sophistication of their civilization. The "stuff" you mentioned them being good at could include being able to establish telepathic connection with your mount via brain implants, which makes steering it a simple matter of thinking about your destination and leaning back in the comfortable seat atop your genetically engineered micro elephant, which can handle finding the optimal route and avoid obstacles, possibly by communicating with his kin to prevent traffic jams. As to why they don't replace biological mounts with AI enabled vehicles operated in the same manner there could be many explanations. Perhaps at some point in their history advanced AI got out of control, so they could be careful about having it interface with the brain. Perhaps they have run out of fossil fuels and rather then go electric, they went biological. This is especially viable if their population is smaller, so they can afford producing the feed for their mounts.

Answer (score 0):

People generally pick the best tool for a given job. So the question really is: Where are animals more useful than machines?

Rough terrain has already been mentioned. Expanding on that: We are now in space. There is a **LOT** of... well, space, in space. Farms could be huge, Australia-style, and the density of people is too low to make road-building a good choice. The same may be true for warp gates or whatever futuristic tech you are using.

Sure, in the cities and the densely populated planets, you have all this fancy tech. But out in the frontier, more simple tools that don't need high-tech factories to build and specialised mechanics to maintain and repair, are the better tool for the job.

Comment: Peasants pick the best tool for a given job. Nobility picks what is in vogue.

Answer (score 0):

At that point, it doesn't really matter to your society. Most things are not transported *at all* if we can simply magic them out of thin air with advanced technology (teleportation, replicators, simulated sensoria).

We are operating in the realm of human whim.

## Why not?

As society approaches post-scarcity, demands for efficiency fall away. There are few compelling reasons for fast overland transport if you can teleport, or project yourself as a hologram, or generate a simulated version of yourself to work while you relax, or otherwise "warp reality" as you put it.

Indeed, the overwhelming power of the prevailing technology allows people to do *what they want* and explore all kinds of preferences. While some people will certainly prefer to race along in a jet-powered car or plane, others might want to trot down the lane on a warm friendly horse that the neighbor's kids feed carrots to as it goes by.

## Social status and artificial scarcity

One of the things it is truly difficult to overcome is the scarcity of skill. It is more difficult to ride a horse than get on a bus. It is more difficult to plow a field with an ox, grow crops, and cook them than to replicate a ready-made meal.

In a post-scarcity society, the choice to do things the hard way signals your values to people: I have taken the time to master this skill, and chose to do it my way. My product may be identical (or inferior) to the synthetic stuff, but it's the history of it rather than the molecules composing the end-state, that is important.

So too for the transportation-animals. The time and inefficiency of transport is a feature, not a bug. The value of the object (or person) being transported increases in proportion to its recipients' anticipation of it. The scarcity is 100% artificial, voluntary, and optional - in other words, it's a game, it's fun.

Answer (score 0):

#### Lack of Fuel

If there is no available fuel for technological solutions, one has to fall back on older solutions that don't require it.  A lack of fuel could easily be explained that it is ALL reserved for the space program.

#### Lack of Manufacturing

A new colony might be built through a terraforming process the includes placing animals in good quantities, but no manufacturing.  New colonist might well travel light, and use what is available.

#### Lack of Interest

If automated system handle deliveries, and VR does your meetings, sightseeing, and the like, then why do you travel?  It might easily be that the only time you travel significant distances is to marry!  And that could be tied up in so many traditions...

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, but not in general**

For special cases much as today. Hobbies / recreation, and for sparse access to rough terrain where the economics of building a road don't work.

In this latter context, it may be that the relative cost of roads has risen in the future. Preserving the environment may have a higher value. Also the demise of fossil fuels means the demise of asphalt. Non-asphalted roads will have either higher maintenance costs (unsurfaced gravel) or higher capital cost (any non-asphalt replacement. Concrete is also bad from a CO2 emissions perspective). So the minor roads that are currently crumbling, may end up never being replaced or replaced with gravel tracks only.

It's possible that artificial legged vehicles may become a thing as robotics advances. Against this idea, mainitaining a plurality of joints that are not just simple rotary sealed-for-life  bearings, may never become as viable as a donkey or horse.

Answer (score 0):

## Lack of roads

It's natural in today's day and age to think that cars are the best form of land based transportation, with smooth paved roads just an inevitable technological progression. But cars have plenty of flaws, we just *made* the environment better for cars.

Try taking a car along a muddy track (don't actually do this). You can get stuck, you could slip and slide down a hill, you could roll - all sorts of other difficult (and sometimes dangerous) situations occur. Sure, a 4WD system improves things, but there's still lots of problems. And each vehicle that goes past rips up the track and makes it less usable for the next guy.

Your environment might be particularly hostile towards cars - swampy, forested, mountainous. These factors also can be hostile towards roads. In a futuristic world with FTL, roads may not be such a priority. Why spend all this effort on making cars work when you can take the space elevator and orbital drop to the other side of the world in an hour?

Without massive effort put into building and maintaining roads, animals just become a much more natural way of getting around. They can work their way through mud, they can navigate around trees, they can find their footing on treacherous mountainous terrain.

### Environmental considerations

Cars pollute. Even replacing ICE with electric or other futuristic tech, rubber or whatever you use for tyres is going to ablate. Perhaps the most reality warping achievement that your world has achieved is regulating pollution.

Answer (score 0):

### Global Warming: Closed vs Open Carbon Cycles

In a world of mass AI automation and bioengineering, things like labor and resources become practically worthless whereas things like having a sustainable environment become ever more important and valuable.

A car and a horse both release about the same amount of greenhouse gases into the air, but the key difference is in where those gases are coming from. Every carbon atom that exits a horse first had to come from eating a plant that absorbed that carbon from the air.  This is called a Closed Carbon Cycle.  In a closed Carbon Cycle, you can have billions of horses and know that you are not causing any damage to the atmosphere because you have to take the carbon out of the air before you can put it back.

In contrast, cars get thier fuel from sequestered sources of carbon like coal and petroleum extracted from the ground. Even making an electric car means burning litteral tons of the stuff.  So, the source of a car's fuel and construction is an Open Carbon Cycle that leads to infinitely pumping more and more carbon into the air until everyone is dead.

So, for your future tech civilization to solve the long-term survival problem we have today, they have made sure to use closed carbon cycles whenever they can, and when they do use open carbon cycles, they have to pay exorbitant fees to have equivalent amounts of CO2 scrubbed from the air and reprocessed into a sequestered form.  The cost of CO2 fees are so high that it is much more economical to own a horse, or genetically engineered equivalent, than it is to own a car.

Answer (score -1):

You justify it by how ever you want or by simply making it so.

In your game, "to include animals used for transportation, how do I justify this" could be simply that is what is done. You do not have to justify game logic. If you want to, OK. If you do not want to, OK. You are not required to justify anything in a game. If the game is interesting enough, then the player has the option to adjust their in-game logic to fit.

Example: In many games faster-than-light travel is a given, not explained with reality, but explained (if explained) with imaginary wanderings of the game developer.

If you really feel a desire to justify it, then those other answers address that, but to answer your question totally: It is as you chose or not justified at all; both being correct and acceptable.

Comment: You have to at least try to fill up plot-holes and logic leaps, otherwise it breaks the immersion. You are of course correct that you can ignore them -ala Final Fantasy, but then you are in the realm of fantastic fairytales and can no longer claim an relation to todays affairs in any way.

Comment: So, fill up plot-holes and logic leaps similar to how many other people do in their daily lives, by the simple minded accepting of what they are told and by refusing to think for themselves. I was giving the option that such people seem to fear, someone (the game developer in this case) states a condition and many others accept that as a given.

Comment: In the end, story is always more important then world-building. World-building is only relevant to readers/users, when it propells a person we feel for onwards. Otherwise it degrades the story. One of the reason why worldbuilding/lore is always optional in games.

Answer (score -1):

A lot depends on how human nature has evolved over the thousands of years. Unless we evolved into a caring sharing ideal communist race where everyone has equal wealth, there will always be the ten percent that own 90% of the wealth and one percent that live in extreme poverty in the barren outlands and they will still find animal transport convenient. Even where everyone is equally wealthy and teleporting technology and advanced AI robotic transport technology is available, animals will still be convenient where land is plentiful and the terrain is rough. Animals are also useful for black market smuggling where they are less noticeable from satellites and might pass for wild animals and are less likely to have tracking devices on them for people who want to live off-grid or  who don't want their transport venerable to being disabled by EMPs. As soon as you buy a vehicle, you will almost certainly have to register and licence it, perhaps having to give a blood sample, a DNA sample and  an eyeball scan and there will almost certainly still be people that don't trust the government with that amount of their personal information, so one way they stay off the system is by using animals instead of vehicles.

There will probably always be people who just prefer animals as it makes them feel connected with nature and find them a comfort, for the same reasons we keep pets when there is no financial reason to do so.